# Django | Not Found issue while updating record

Tags: python, django

[image: This is the update form template front end]

[image: this is the issue I get when click on form submit button]

[image: This is the coding of update template]

**Other Coding I did**

***urls.py of web app path adding***:

```
path('update/updaterecord/<int:id>', views.updaterecord, name='updaterecord'),
```

***views.py file of web app : update coding info***:

```
def updaterecord(request, id):
  first = request.POST['first']
  last = request.POST['last']
  member = Members.objects.get(id=id)
  member.firstname = first
  member.lastname = last
  member.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Comment: What is the result if you use `action="{% url 'updaterecord' mymember.id %}"` ?

Comment: thanks dear
issue solved, it was forward slash missing in url path file

Comment: Please don't post your code as images.

Comment: I am new, can please reason of this, mean why not as images? so I keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Your `<form action="">` has a slash at the end, just remove it at it should be good.
The url needs to match what is in your `urlpatterns[]`:

```
path('update/updaterecord/int:id', views.updaterecord, name='updaterecord'),
```

The resulting url will be:
`members/update/updaterecord/8`

Answer (score 0):

Your `action=""` is relative to the current URL since it doesn't have a leading slash.

Since you're on `/members/update/8`, the `action` URL segment `updaterecord/8`   turns that to the absolute URL `/members/update/updaterecord/8` you're seeing 404.

If you want your form to target the current page (which is correct in this case), just empty it or get rid of it:

```
<form method="post">
```

is sufficient in this case.

Beyond that, please look into Django's form modules and generic views; you're currently doing a lot of manual work you don't need to.